# Remove logo at top left from sharepoint online hub site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, style.css, customization

I'm beginner in SharePoint Online so trying to remove logo showing at top left side using the Alternate CSS URL option in the Master page.

Logo that I need to remove is shown here along with its Inspect element view: http://prntscr.com/t6kpod

I used the below code in CSS:

```
div[class^="logoImg-62"] {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Need to know what i'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

You may try with the below CSS or PnP PowerShell.

**CSS**

```
div[class^="logoCell-119"]
 {
    display: none !important;
}
```

OR

```
img[src*='siteIcon'] { display: block;}
```

Note:

- Customizing or script editor web part is not supported in modern SharePoint online, so as an alternate we can deploy and make use of modern script editor web part.

**How to inject custom CSS or javascript code in modern SharePoint Online?**

We can use the **modern script editor web part** for this. The good thing is that we don't o need to develop this web part from the beginning, we can just deploy the modern script editor web part which is built on SPFx (alternate of classic script editor web part), we can get the modern script editor web part from [here](https://medium.com/niftit-sharepoint-blog/add-the-script-editor-webpart-back-to-sharepoint-modern-experience-688a7b7208e4).

For details refer to the below article:

[SharePoint Online, how to hide the SharePoint logo on a list using css or jquery](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/a26af6dd-f15f-4461-a10e-1e62f517ea46/sharepoint-online-how-to-hide-the-sharepoint-logo-on-a-list-using-css-or-jquery?forum=sharepointgeneral)

[SharePoint Online Logo Link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/sharepoint-online-logo-link/c22c2bb3-ddd3-4070-80bc-1c70e9c0f9ec)

Comment: OP wants to remove/hide only site logo and not the complete top banner.

Comment: yes i need to only remove site logo not the whole banner.

Comment: You can use this CSS class^="logoCell-119"

Comment: customization in modern isn't supported anymore, only way is to do via SPFx Application Customizer

Comment: No need to develop this from the begining, you can just deploy the modern script editor web part which is built on SPFx (alternate of classic script editor web part), get the modern script editor web part from here. https://medium.com/niftit-sharepoint-blog/add-the-script-editor-webpart-back-to-sharepoint-modern-experience-688a7b7208e4

Answer (score 0):

Try using below CSS:

```
<style>
    div[class^="logoCell-"] {
       display: none !important;
    }
</style>
```

Also, if it is not working using alternate CSS (As modern pages does not support this) then you can try adding it using **SPFx Application customizer** (if you want to hide it from all modern pages) or [Modern Script Editor webpart](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor) (if you want to hide it from only one page).

**References**:

1. [Inject Custom CSS on SharePoint Modern Pages using SPFx Extensions](https://tahoeninjas.blog/2018/05/08/inject-custom-css-on-sharepoint-modern-pages-using-spfx-extensions/)
2. [Supported customizations for "modern" pages](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-pages?#supported-customizations-for-modern-pages)
3. [Sharepoint 365 - Add Custom CSS to Modern Pages](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/230061/sharepoint-365-add-custom-css-to-modern-pages)

---

**Update**:

You can also try this:

1. Click on settings (gear icon) > Change the look > Header
2. Upload white transparent image as site logo and site thumbnail
3. Save

Check my answer given on this thread for more information: [SharePoint Header Site remove](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/sharepoint-header-site-remove/m-p/3695775/highlight/true#M66779)

Comment: I tried using this but no luck http://prntscr.com/t6vwoz

Comment: Try using the exact CSS given in my answer. do not use the number part after `-` as it changes sometimes

Comment: do i need to use the <style> tag as well?

Comment: Yes, you can use the style tag...see my updated answer.

Comment: thanks, i updated in the file in  Site Assets location and update the path in the Alternate CSS URL as /sites/Techo/SiteAssets/LogoRemove.css , but can't see the change.

Comment: I did test on inspect element with display: none and it worked there though as you can see here http://prntscr.com/t6w33o

Comment: Hi @Xam, Applying custom CSS via `AlternateCSSUrl` web property is not supported for modern pages. Check more detail [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-pages?#supported-customizations-for-modern-pages).

Comment: So, you have to use another solution of using **SPFx Application Customizer** as I suggested in my answer. Please try that. Also check [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/230061/sharepoint-365-add-custom-css-to-modern-pages) for more information.

Comment: ok will try that but that will a bit tricky to do

Comment: Yes, I understand. But thats the only way to customize modern pages in SharePoint more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this requires no CSS or scripting. It's to upload a 192x192 transparent image.