# Is it possible to apply custom CSS to the SharePoint Online Site Content page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, css, modern-experience, site-contents

Is it possible to apply a snippet of CSS to the SharePoint **Site Contents** page of a SharePoint site?

I would like to tweak it slightly with some styling.

Comment: [https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/230061/sharepoint-365-add-custom-css-to-modern-pages](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/230061/sharepoint-365-add-custom-css-to-modern-pages)

Comment: I found a more reliable approach. I can learn how to build a chrome or firefox extension that will modify the html and css on any targeted page(s).  This should in theory do what my I am trying to accomplish in the long run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can add custom CSS or JS to modern pages using SPFx Application customizer.

For more information, check my answer at: [What is the best practice for getting JS and CSS files into a SharePoint Modern Page?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/277352/what-is-the-best-practice-for-getting-js-and-css-files-into-a-sharepoint-modern/277353#277353)

---

**Note**: DOM manipulation & CSS customizations are not recommended by Microsoft and some of your customization may break if Microsoft changes HTML element id/classes in new release updates.

Comment: hi, i tried this, i can even see the script in DEV TOOLS in SiteContent page, but it just not running

is there something else or new that needs to be done?